# Create a function object with empty prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is it possible to create a function in IE >= 9 with null as its prototype?  (like in the code below, which unfortunately, works only in Chrome, FF, and Safari)

```
var F = function(){};
F.__proto__ = Object.create(null);
```

Comment: What do you mean? IEs don't support `__proto__`

Comment: Are you using function `F` as a constructor function ?

Comment: Well, in the end, yes, it will be used as a constructor (in a compiled to javascript language). But the code is going to be more complex. The core idea is that there will be one more line `F.prototype = F` after that, so all objects created from F will see the attributes of their class; i.e. `f = new F(); F.foo = 123; print(f.foo);`

Comment: And I don't want instances of F to have anything inherited from function, that's why the `Object.create(null)` business.

Comment: Why not just set `F.prototype = Object.create(null);`.

Comment: `__proto__ ` is normally used to get the prototype of an already instantiated object.  Like `[].__proto__` (which would be `Array.prototype`).

Comment: If you use `F.prototype = Object.create(null)`, then `F` will still have `apply` and other JS function's methods/properties. And that's what I don't want it to have.  In other word, I want to create a function, that is callable, but does have nothing in its prototype.

Comment: Then use `F = Object.create(null)`

Comment: You could overwrite `.apply` and `.call` (and the other properties you don't want to be accessible) on the function object itself. But whatever you do, it's likely that it's still possible to use `Function.prototype.apply.call(F, [arguments])`, and after reading the other comments that might not be an issue in your case.

Comment: @Sniffer: That would only affect objects created through `new F()`, not `F` itself.

Comment: @Sniffer: Ah, I didn't see your first comment, sorry.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes, I can overwrite them, but if someone adds something to `Function.prototype` -- all my objects will have it, and that's why I want to disconnect from function.  If `Function.prototype.apply` works, that's fine, `F` is going to be a constructor function anyways.

Comment: Well, but that's the problem with every prototype. If someone adds something to `Object.prototype`, you have the same problem. That's why one should avoid extending the prototype ;) There is only so much you can guard your code against.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, that's the sad reality ;) Anyways, the whole point of the question was just to make sure that it's not possible to do without using non-standard `__proto__`.

Comment: @rvignacio: Then `F` is not gonna be `[[callable]]`.

Comment: The only way to change the prototype of an *existing* object is indeed `__proto__`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes. I was wondering if it's possible to *extend* the `Function` object, keeping its ability to be called, but loosing its prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's impossible without reassigning a [[prototype]] to a function object. IE does neither support the nonstandard [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) nor the ES6 method [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

The only custom callable objects are functions which you create with function expressions/declarations or the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). However, all of these methods will create function objects which have their [[prototype]] [set to](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2) the builtin [`Function.prototype` object](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4).

---

> F will be used as a constructor (in a compiled to javascript language). But the code is going to be more complex. The core idea is that there will be one more line `F.prototype = F` after that, so all objects created from F will see the attributes of their class; i.e. `f = new F(); F.foo = 123; print(f.foo);`

Don't do that. While F is a (constructor) function, your instances are not, so there's no reason to let them inherit from it. Just comile your class attributes to `F.prototype.foo = 123;`. Or compile any accesses to static properties (where "instances see class attributes") to use the `F` object instead, so `print(F.foo)`.

Comment: "Don't do that. While F is a (constructor) function, your instances are not [snip]"


Why? If you do `F.prototype = F`, then instances of `new F` will be regular JS objects.  There is no performance penalty for that, but it gives you more flexible way of working with statics (and makes compiler simpler).  What's the real downside?

Comment: As for the `__proto__`, yeah, I guess that's the only way.  It also looks like `Function.prototype` is read-only, thus eliminating all possible hacks around it too.

Comment: On the bright side, `__proto__` has landed in IE11: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br212465(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Yes, they would be regular JS objects - not callable, so you don't want them to inherit from `Function.prototype`. However, `F` *is* a function and *should* inherit from `Function.prototype`. That means that the instances of `F` should not inherit from `F` like you had planned. If you could tell me more about (or link) your compiler, I can explain you how to *keep* static properties simple.

Comment: Thank you, Bergi.  I'll send you a link once it's open-sourced ;)

Comment: (the topic of discussion is quickly shifting away from the original question, so if you want to continue -- shoot me an email at yselivanov () gmail.com

Comment: Actually that's what the SO chat is for :-) BTW, I've [modified your tests slightly](http://jsperf.com/function-self-prototype/2) and regular objects are quite as fast when the prototype was not overwritten.